# Scheduled Reminders don't pick up changes to Templates

Tags: scheduled-reminders, message-templates

We have observed the following behaviour with a Scheduled Membership Reminder using an Email Message Template.  When the Template used by a Reminder is edited, the Reminder continues to use the old text and does not pick up the change.  This is still happening a few days later.  Clearing caches doesn’t help.

Looking behind the scenes I can see that if a Reminder is set up to use a Template, then the record in the civicrm_action_schedule table contains a link to the Template, but also a copy of the Template content.  That copy doesn’t get updated when the Template is changed. If a different Template is selected, then that text is picked up correctly.

Is there any reason for this behaviour, since it looks like a bug to me?

With thanks,
Tony

Comment: agree it is a pain that you have to edit/save to pick up the changes. wonder if a sch. job could do it

Comment: To me, the more obvious behaviour would be that it uses the template as it is when the reminders are sent, but if it is copying the template content it seems intentional.  What's the reason for that?